# How do I use the power rule with $4x^2 - 2$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Every website I look at only shows the power use with a single term example or polynomial. Could somebody please give me a step by step breakdown of using the power rule to find $f'(x)$ where $f(x) = 4x^2 - 2$?

Comment: The power rule is linear, so you can use it term by term, and then you can combine the results.

Comment: Exactly, how does the power rule affect constants? I know that 4x^2 goes to 8x but how does -2 work?

Comment: " single term example or polynomial": your case **is** a polynomial, why can't you derive it ?

Comment: @danishanish: The derivative of any constant term is zero.  This makes sense intuitively, since the derivative represents a rate of change, and a constant doesn't change.

Answer (score 10):

First, the derivative is a *linear operator*.  This means that
$$ (f(x) + g(x))' = f'(x) + g'(x) $$
and 
$$ (cf)'(x) = cf'(x)$$
So, in the case that you give, $h(x) = 4x^2 - 2$, you can look at this as
$$ h(x) = f(x) + g(x) \quad \text{where} \quad f(x) = 4x^2 \quad \text{and} \quad g(x) = -2 $$
Then, you have
\begin{align*}
 h'(x) &= (f(x) + g(x))' \\
 &= f'(x) + g'(x) \\
 &= (4x^2)' + (-2)' \\
 &= 4(x^2)' + 0 \\
 &= 4 (2x) \\
 &= 8x.
\end{align*}

Of course, once you practice taking the derivatives of polynomials, this will all seem like a single step.  We could even add in a few more steps to the above to pull out the constants, etc.  Hopefully this is clear already though.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks!

Comment: "this will all seem like a single step." This is very important. As long as you need more than one second to derive a quadratic polynomial, you know you need to practice a lot more!

Comment: @5xum coming back a while later to respond, yes - deriving any quadratic polynomial is extremely simple and fast now - thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 5):

There are already a ton of good answers to this, but I can't help myself:

Just for fun, since you wrote **product rule** in the title and because everyone else showed you the power rule, I'll show you how to use the product rule for this. ;)

Remember that the product rule is that $$(f(x)\cdot g(x))' = f'(x)\cdot g(x) + f(x)\cdot g'(x)$$

In your case we have $$h(x) = 4x^2-2$$  Using what we know about the difference of squares, we can factor this as $$\begin{align}h(x) &= 4x^2 -2 \\ &= (2x-\sqrt{2})(2x+\sqrt{2})\end{align}$$

Now we can use the product rule.  Just let $\require{enclose}f(x) = 2x-\sqrt{2}$ and $g(x) = 2x+\sqrt{2}$.  Then $$\begin{align}h'(x) &= \left(2x-\sqrt{2}\right)'\left(2x+\sqrt{2}\right) + \left(2x-\sqrt{2}\right)\left(2x+\sqrt{2}\right)' \\ &= \left[\left(2x\right)'-\left(\sqrt{2}\right)'\right]\left(2x+\sqrt{2}\right) + \left(2x-\sqrt{2}\right)\left[\left(2x\right)'+\left(\sqrt{2}\right)'\right] \\ &= \left[2-0\right]\left(2x+\sqrt{2}\right) + \left(2x-\sqrt{2}\right)\left[2+0\right] \\ &= 4x+2\sqrt{2} + 4x-2\sqrt{2} \\ &= \enclose{box}{8x}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 3):

$(4x^2-2)'=(4x^2)'-(2)'=4(x^2)'-0=4\cdot 2x=8x$.

Remember that the derivative of a constant is always $0$.

Answer (score 3):

$$
\begin{split}
\frac{df(x)}{dx}
   = \frac{d}{dx} \left[ 4x^2 - 2\right]
   = \frac{d\left[ 4x^2 \right]}{dx} - \frac{d [2]}{dx}
   = 4 \frac{d\left[ x^2 \right]}{dx} - 0
   = 4 \cdot 2x
   = 8x
\end{split}
$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Let $g(x)=2x$. Then $f(x)=4x^2=\left(g(x)\right)^2$ Therefore $f'(x)=2\cdot g(x)\cdot g'(x)$

Answer (score 2):

There's a separate rule (the sum rule) for taking the derivative of **any** sum of terms:

(f(x) + g(x))' = f'(x) + g'(x)

Use this to split the sum into its terms and take the derivative of each term.